# e2fsck "Memory allocation failed"

Tags: centos, fsck

I'm trying to fix an ext4 volume by using `e2fsck` but I get the error "Memory allocation failed." The only suggestion I found by research is adding a temporary directory to */etc/e2fsck.conf* to be used instead of RAM. This is my modified *e2fsck.conf*:

```
broken_system_clock = 1
[scratch_files]
directory = /var/cache/e2fsck`
```

As you might guess, this didn't help; I still get "Memory allocation failed." I know the option works though because there are files created under */var/cache/e2fsck*. So I'm assuming this error is not caused by the system's memory being exhausted. I would really appreciate any help.

**Edit:**
`free -h` gives me this:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         47G         76G         43M        1.4G         77G
Swap:          4.0G        4.0G         32K`
```

Comment: `free`? Do you have any swap space active? See `man swapon` for emergency swapping to file.

Comment: See edit. Could I simply create a new directory and `swapon dir` to increase my free swap space?

Comment: I repeat, see `man swapon`. You need more swap or fewer processes.

Comment: I looked at the the manual. [Here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-swap-adding.html) they say, to add swap space, I should (1)`dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapdir`, (2)`mkswap /swapdir`, and then (3)`swapon /swapdir`. Just wanted to confirm that `swapon /swapdir` by itself would be sufficient.

Comment: I just add 30 more gigs of swap space and still got the same error: "Memory allocation failed."

Comment: Maybe some corruption in the filesystem is causing fsck to try to allocate a ridiculous amount of memory. If that's the case it will be hard to trace. You can start by trying the fsck with `-v` and see how many passes it gets through before dying.

Comment: If you are on a 32bit OS and you can move to a 64 bit version, you should try that.